# How can I filter dataframes from a list using Purrr?

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

I have a list of dataframes. There are two types of dataframes, one listing names and ages, the other listing tests and grades (as in the 'combined list' below).

```
df1 <- data.frame(name = c("Alice", "Bob"),
                 age = c(23, 41))
df2 <- data.frame(test = c("Geography", "Science"),
                  grade = c("A", "B"))
df3 <- data.frame(name = c("Claire", "David"),
                  age= c(50, 32))
df4 <- data.frame(test = c("Geography", "Science"),
                  grade = c("B", "B"))

combined_list <- c(df1,df2,df3,d4)
```

I would like to subset the list into a dataframe consisting of only the names and the ages, so it would look something like this:

```
   name age
1 Alice  23
2   Bob  41
3 Claire 50
4 David  32
```

I found the Keep function of the Purrr package, which should be able to filter the list based on a condition, but I haven't found a way to make it work. This is what I've tried so far:

```
library(purrr)
purrr:keep(function(x) filter(!name=NULL))
```

How can I make this work? Are there other solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We create the logical condition to `Filter` the elements of the `list` where it returns a single TRUE.  It can be done by wrapping with `all` after creating a logical vector with `%in%` i.e. subsetting only those elements having both 'name', and 'age' as column names.  Then, we bind the `list` elements to a single data.frame with `bind_rows`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
keep(combined_list, ~  all(c("name", 'age') %in% names(.x))) %>% 
     bind_rows
```

-output

```
#     name age
#1  Alice  23
#2    Bob  41
#3 Claire  50
#4  David  32
```

---

Or another option is to bind all the datasets together, then `select` only the relevant columns and remove the `NA` rows

```
bind_rows(combined_list) %>% 
    select(name, age) %>% 
    na.omit
```

---

In `base R`, we can use `Filter` with `rbind` inside `do.call`

```
do.call(rbind, Filter(function(x) 
      all(c("name", "age") %in% names(x)), combined_list))
#    name age
#1  Alice  23
#2    Bob  41
#3 Claire  50
#4  David  32
```

#### data

```
combined_list <- list(df1,df2,df3,df4)
```